# how to build a c file into a shared object (library) in linux

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I need to build a hello world function into a dynamic library. I'm coding in C language on linux.
Can anyone help with some sample code doing that? And also for linking against the generated library?

Comment: Succinctly, you don't: DLL is a Windows concept.  You create a shared library or shared object, which normally ends `.so` (but ends `.dylib` or perhaps `.bundle` on Mac OS X, and `.sl` on older HP-UX).

Comment: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html

Comment: Please describe what you already know and what you've already tried. Research gcc's options, in particular -dynamic.

Comment: Thanks guys for the information. The link also seems to be a good resource. @Arkadiy It is actually the first time for me to do something with shared libraries. I've just tried the answer posted by aftnix and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First compile files to object code

```
$gcc -Wall -fPIC -c test1.c test2.c
```

`-fPIC` means that it will produce position independent code.

```
$gcc -shared -o libtest.so test1.o test2.o
```

Comment: Thank you.. concise and precise :)

Answer (score -2):

Dig up a copy of libtool and use it.  It knows a LOT of the (disturbingly variable) details of how to compile and link a shared library on a large number of operating systems.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Using-libtool.html

Comment: Oh dear god no! Don't. Just don't. Libtool is even more evil than autoconf and automake put together.